# Photoshop - Hiding layers for exporting slices

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, export, slices

I want to set certain layers to be hidden when exporting a slice.

More specifically, I have a banner slice with a headline within it. On the actual HTML page, that headline is actual text displayed over the image.

When I export the image within Photoshop, it is a hassle to hide that PS text layer before exporting. Is there any way to set it to remember to hide?

Answer (score 1):

For me is quite a simple thing to click on the eye icon to hide it lol.   IF I know I'm not gonna use it, I just hide it from the begining, and I use the rulers to measure the space.    Anyways,  this is maybe what you gotta look for,  **scripting in photoshop: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544382/function-to-show-hide-layer-with-photoshop-script-jsx)**

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to set up two layer comps. One for export and one for presentation/designing. Then you can just toggle between them.

Another little trick is is to put everything that needs to be sliced/exported in a smart object. Open the smart object and do the slices within it. This way you can have multiple slice sets in one document and they won't interfere with one another.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with an editable multi-layered .PSD document it is advisable that any imagery you would like to not have displayed for the final export is hidden within your 'layers' palette.

Hide each element 1 by 1, then export the slices.  Should keep everything you want on 1 page.

Hope that helps!